# How can I stop cl.exe from terminating when a user logs out?

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

We have an automated build server that produces builds using Visual Studio 2005 and [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) (on Windows XP x64).  Normally nobody is logged into the system, but occasionally we have to log in via Remote Desktop in order to perform maintenance.

We have noticed that if `cl.exe` is running (Microsoft's C++ compiler) at the instant we log out from remote desktop, then `cl.exe` will terminate with error result 4:

> Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 4 returned from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\cl.exe'.

This obviously causes the current build to fail with a pretty mysterious message. **Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run ccnet service under some other, non-admin, account.

Comment: The service runs under a valid user account on the domain.  It isn't a local system account.  The user I am logging in as through remote desktop is a different account again.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I stumbled over this question when searching for what `error PRJ0002 : Error result 4 returned from ... cl.exe` actually means.

I can give the following info:

This happened to me on a Windows XP (32 bit) test box for our automated build, and the build-run was definitely run under a *different* user account than the user I logged out with.

However, I *know* that there are *no* problems on our production build servers on log-out, but these servers run Win 2003 Server and Win 2008R2 Server resp. (There, I only have a problem if *the same* user used to run the build logs out, but we can easily avoid that.)

**So I would *suspect* that this problem will not occur on *Windows Server* OSs, but only on Win XP.** (Can't give any opinion on Win7.)